# Setting Up a Double Integral Over a Region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\iint_R(x+y)\ \mathrm dy\ \mathrm dx$$

where the region $R$ is bounded by $y=\frac{1}{9}x, x=6$ and the x−axis.

can anyone show me how to set this up? I thought that it would integrated by $x$ from $0$ to $6$ since $x=6$ and then $y$ would be from $0$ to $\frac{2}{3}$, because

$$\frac{1}{9} \times 6=\frac{2}{3}$$

and doing this I got integrate $\int_0^6\int_0^{\frac23}(x+y)dydx$ but this wasn't right.

Comment: Use mathjax to write mathematics here. Is it $\;\frac1{9x}\;$ or $\;\frac x9=\frac19x\;$ ? I'm *guessing* the latter as with the former there is the problematic $\;x=0\;$ line...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is $\;y=\frac19x\;,\;\;y=0\;,\;\;x=6\;$ , the integral can be put in the form

$$\int_0^6\int_0^{\frac19x}(x+y)dydx$$

Comment: so you dont need to do anything with the y=(1/9)x? you just plug it in

Comment: @NoahDukehart I'm not sure I understand your question. If you draw the integration region you can see that as $\;x\;$ goes from zero to $\;6\;$ , $\;y\;$ "sweeps" the region between $\;y=0\;$ and $\;y=\frac19x\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

How do you define the set of points in the blue region in terms of inequalities?

$$\text{BlueRegion}=\{(x,y)|0 \le x \le 6 , 0 \le y \le \color{red}{\text{?}}\}$$

There is also another way to do it

$$\text{BlueRegion}=\{(x,y)|0 \le y \le \frac 23 , 0 \le x \le \text{?}\}$$

[image]

Comment: @NoahDukehart: Did this help? :)

Answer (score 0):

You start with the inner integral:

$\int_0^{1/9x}(x+y)dy=[xy+1/2y^2]_0^{1/9x}=10/9x+1/162x^2$

and this function you integrate with dx on the limits of $0,6$.